# How to build a multiway tree from lists

Tags: algorithm, tree, multiway-tree

I have to build a multiway tree by merging multiple lists together. I am trying to find an efficient algorithm to do that.

- There can be identical lists
- List elements are not unique. The paths to these elements are
- The tree starts with a null root element

The lists contains elements that are not unique. The path to each element is a key,

For instances, using lists :

- A-B-C-D-E
- A-B-C-B
- F-B-C-C
- A-E-F
- A-C-D
- A-B-C-D-E

The following tree can be built :

[image]

The first algorithm I implemented builds the tree by creating the root node and adding the lists to it one after the other :

1. Create root node
2. Select the first list
3. If the first element of the list is already a children of the root node, select it. Otherwise, insert the element as a child.
4. If the next element of the list is already a children the previously selected or inserted child, select it. Otherwise, insert the element as a child.
5. Repeat step 4 until the list is empty
6. Select the next array and go to step 3. If there is no other list, stop.

Most of the resource I have found to build or merge tree refers to binary trees. As such, I am wondering if there is a better algorithm to build a multiway tree in my case ?

Comment: After a quick glance you algorithm looks right, but I would change the terminology. Instead of saying 'first element of the list' I would use `head`. And instead  of `saying next element of the list` you should think of passing a new list with the head removed, and then the using the new `head`. This way you are always processing the head of a list. Instead of saying `until the list is empty` think `until the head empty`. If you know the input list will always be fixed then you could use a perfect hash which would be faster, but you don't not that in your question.

Comment: Great, thank you for your help !